# A Chinese Poem About Weather, Crops...And Clipper Ships?

Tags: simplified-characters, poetry

I've been trying to translate passages from a poem about weather and seasons. There's a particularly knotty passage below I'm trying to unravel:

"至于雾水那是亟待被理解的事物
墙面和我的手臂是时间的快船"

My rough translation is as follows:

"The Fog, on the other hand, is a matter that urgently needs to be understood.
The wall and my arm are the age of swift boats."

Does the phrases "时间的快船" refer to the Age of Sail and its clipper ships? Or does the second verse have a completely different meaning?

Comment: Quite certain the second verse contains a metaphor, where 牆面和我的手臂 are the tenor (本體), 是 is the copula (繫詞), and 時間的快船 is the vehicle (喻體). But more context is definitely needed, especially when it comes to poems. Also, your translation ‘age of sail’ centres on 時間 rather than the supposed 快船. Perhaps ‘the speedboat of time’? Reminds me of the last line of *The Great Gatsby*.

Answer (score 2):

I think 时间的快船 is referring to something like the fast boat of time, and what ever before is what is the boat. This may be talking about the flow of time.